# Multiple RegEx negation matching

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I have the following RegEx patterns:

1. `"[0-9]{4,5}\.FU|[0-9]{4,5}\.NG|[0-9]{4,5}\.SP|[0-9]{4,5}\.T|JGB[A-Z][0-9]|JNI[A-Z][0-9]|JN4F[A-Z][0-9]|JNM[A-Z][0-9]|JTI[A-Z][0-9]|JTM[A-Z][0-9]|NIY[A-Z][0-9]|SSI[A-Z][0-9]|JNI[A-Z][0-9]-[A-Z][0-9]|JTI[A-Z][0-9]-[A-Z][0-9]"` ===> matches 8411.T or JNID8
2. `"[0-9]{4,5}\.HK|HSI[A-Z][0-9]|HMH[A-Z][0-9]|HCEI[A-Z][0-9]|HCEI[A-Z][0-9]-[A-Z][0-9]"` ==> matches 9345.HK or HCEIU9-A9
3. `".*\.SI|SFC[A-Z][0-9]"` ==> matches 8345.SI or SFCX8

How can I obtain a RegEx from the negation of these patterns?
I want to match strings that match neither of these 3 patterns:
e.g. I want to match 8411.ABC, but not any of the aforementioned strings (8411.T, HCEIU-A9, 8345.SI, etc.).

I've tried (just to exclude 2 and 3 for instance, but it doesn't work):

```
^(?!((.*\.SI|SFC[A-Z][0-9])|([0-9]{4,5}\.HK|HSI[A-Z][0-9]|HMH[A-Z][0-9]|HCEI[A-Z][0-9]|HCEI[A-Z][0-9]-[A-Z][0-9])))
```

Comment: `^(?!.*pattern1)(?!.*pattern2)(?!.*pattern3)`

Comment: I've tried but to no avail.

Comment: Please include that attempt and describe what you expect.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: The `HSIT9` should not be matched acc. to the Regex 2. Anf `HCEIU-A9` is not matched with your regex. I think you must wrap the patterns with `(?:...)`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iNBS4a/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you please post this as an answer? It works correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea here is to place the patterns into `(?!.*<pattern>)` negative lookaheads anchored at the start of the string (`^`). The difficulty here is that you patterns contain unanchored alternations, and if not grouped, the `.*` before the patterns will only refer to the first alternative (i.e. all the subsequent alternatives will only be negated at the start of the string.

Thus, your pattern formula is `^(?!.*(?:<PATTERN1>))(?!.*(?:<PATTERN2>))(?!.*(?:<PATTERN3>))`. Note that `.+` or `.*` at the end is optional if you need to just get a boolean result. Note that in the last pattern, you need to remove the `.*` in the first alternative, it won't make sense to use `.*.*`.

Use

```
^(?!.*(?:[0-9]{4,5}\.FU|[0-9]{4,5}\.NG|[0-9]{4,5}\.SP|[0-9]{4,5}\.T|JGB[A-Z][0-9]|JNI[A-Z][0-9]|JN4F[A-Z][0-9]|JNM[A-Z][0-9]|JTI[A-Z][0-9]|JTM[A-Z][0-9]|NIY[A-Z][0-9]|SSI[A-Z][0-9]|JNI[A-Z][0-9]-[A-Z][0-9]|JTI[A-Z][0-9]-[A-Z][0-9]))(?!.*(?:[0-9]{4,5}\.HK|HSI[A-Z][0-9]|HMH[A-Z][0-9]|HCEI[A-Z][0-9]|HCEI[A-Z][0-9]-[A-Z][0-9]))(?!.*(?:\.SI|SFC[A-Z][0-9])).+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iNBS4a/1/).

You may also contract the formula to `^(?!.*(?:<PATTERN1>|<PATTERN2>|<PATTERN3>))`:

```
^(?!.*(?:[0-9]{4,5}\.FU|[0-9]{4,5}\.NG|[0-9]{4,5}\.SP|[0-9]{4,5}\.T|JGB[A-Z][0-9]|JNI[A-Z][0-9]|JN4F[A-Z][0-9]|JNM[A-Z][0-9]|JTI[A-Z][0-9]|JTM[A-Z][0-9]|NIY[A-Z][0-9]|SSI[A-Z][0-9]|JNI[A-Z][0-9]-[A-Z][0-9]|JTI[A-Z][0-9]-[A-Z][0-9]|[0-9]{4,5}\.HK|HSI[A-Z][0-9]|HMH[A-Z][0-9]|HCEI[A-Z][0-9]|HCEI[A-Z][0-9]-[A-Z][0-9]|\.SI|SFC[A-Z][0-9])).+
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iNBS4a/2).

Comment: What is the purpose of "?:"? what does it do?

Comment: See [What is a non-capturing group? What does a question mark followed by a colon (?:) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471). Just groups alternatives without storing the value in the memory.